# How to show the whole file in diffview in gitkraken

Tags: git-diff, gitkraken

Right now, when I go to the diffview of a file in gitkraken, it more or less exactly shows only the changed lines. Is it somehow possible to see the whole file with the changes highlighted? Seems like a really basic requirement to me.

Answer (score 1):

As of KitKraken 6.1.4, there are two ways to view the whole file, depending on wheter you want to see the old and the modified version side by side or just the modified version:

1. In the top right of the diff view, change from *Hunk View* (which only shows hunks, as the name suggests) to *Split View*: This will show the whole file in the old and the new (modified) version:

[image: Highlighted SplitView]

2. In the top center of the diff view, change from *Diff View* to *File View*. This will show the whole file in the modified version on the whole screen:

[image: Highlighted File View]